# API level 30 gives language not supported error code for Hindi

Tags: android, android-studio, text-to-speech, android-api-levels

I implement the text to speech which is working fine till android API level 28 for Hindi but in Android API level 30 it returns the error code -2 (Language not support).

```
private void setTextTospeech() {
    textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(mContext, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                if (language.toLowerCase().contains(langaugeCodeEnglish)) {
                    int result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(new Locale("en", "IN"));
                    if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                        //Toast.makeText(mContext, result + " is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e("Text2SpeechWidget", result + " is not supported");
                    }
                } else {
                    int result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(new Locale("hi", "IN"));
                    if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.forLanguageTag("hin"));
                        } else {
                            //  Toast.makeText(mContext, result + "Language is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.e("Text2SpeechWidget", result + "Language is not supported");
                        }
                        Log.e("Text2SpeechWidget", result + " is not supported");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}


private void speak(String s, String text) {
        try{
            float pitch = (float) 0.62;
            float speed = (float) 0.86;
            textToSpeech.setSpeechRate(speed);
            textToSpeech.setPitch(pitch);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                textToSpeech.speak(s, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, bundle, null);
                textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, bundle, null);
            } else {
                HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
                param.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
                textToSpeech.speak(s, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, param);
                textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, param);
            }
        }catch (Exception ae){
            ae.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

As per new docs. I also add a queries tag inside manifest tag.

```
<queries>
   ...
  <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.TTS_SERVICE" />
  </intent>
 </queries>
```

Comment: i dont think there's a problem with your question, but it doesn't directly involve android studio, except for the fact that you're using it to create your project, so it shouldn't be added as a tag :)

Comment: I just checked with the getAvailableLanguages(). Android 11 just provides support to 7 languages deu_Deu, eng_USA, rus_RUS, fra_FRA, ita_ITA, eng_GBR, spa_ESP.  Is there any way or library which will be used to support Hindi in text to speech for Android 11 ?